# Spark: Count frequency of all pairs

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

It's best to explain this problem with an example.

Original Data

```
Key | Value
-----------
A   | 1
A   | 2
B   | 3
B   | 4
B   | 5
C   | 3
C   | 4
```

Step 1: Group by A and collect value into a list

```
A | (1,2)
B | (3,4,5)
C | (3,4)
```

Step 2: Collect all combinations into a list

```
A | [(1,2)]
B | [(3,4), (3,5), (4,5)]
C | [(3,4)]
```

Step 3. Count frequency of pairs

```
Pairs | Count
-------------
(1,2) | 1
(3,4) | 2
(3,5) | 1
(4,5) | 1
```

I would like to go from Original Data to Step 3. I have a script right now that does something like Step 1 and Step 2, however it's quite slow and usually runs out of memory on Spark (I'm using AWS Glue).

Is there a way to do this efficiently in Spark?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just self join and aggregate - `df.alias("a").join(df.alias("b"), Seq("Key")).groupBy($"a.Value", $"b.Value").count`? Join could be a bottleneck, but at least you'll skip `collect_list`.